# Ubuntu 20 R version, cannot install MXnet with rpkg

Tags: r, ubuntu, makefile, cmake

I have tried to install MXnet for R on Ubtuntu 20. I have followed exactly the instructions here

https://mxnet.apache.org/versions/1.4.1/install/ubuntu_setup.html#install-the-mxnet-package-for-r

After few hours of compilation, I have (I believe) successfully reached the end. When reaching Step 5 and typing

make rpkg

I got

make: *** No rule to make target 'rpkg'.  Stop.

Any clue would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't this really a question for the developers of that package?

Comment: Did you `cd incubator-mxnet` before running that? There is too little to go on here, whether for us here or for the developers. When you submit a bug report to the devs, I suggest you include console output to indicate how far it went and any errors/warnings, etc.

Comment: I did everything you mention, following the link above, without success. I simply followed the instructions given on the site, step by step. Without a proper installation manual, all the good work is gone lost.